# An alternative way to loop through large dataset

Tags: php, xml

I have a table that contains a user_id, and an items field.  The user_id is just an int with the user's id, and the items is an xml structured object in a 'text' field.  I want to be able to see statistics about the player items. i.e. who has the most of some item, the average wealth of everyone, etc.

I currently have to loop through each row and then again create a SimpleXMLElement and loop thru that and filter given a specific criteria.

The structure is like this:


inventory

if I want to do a query to count all of the items with item id 332 for example, this query takes like 3-4 seconds. We expect there to be 50k+ rows(currently 28k), so if there is any other way I can speed this process up, it would be great.

Comment: Do u need every single field? Have u consider regex?

Comment: Please mention your database, as it has implications here (you might be able to do it all in the database).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about using mysql like ?

for example

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE inventory like '%<itemid>332</itemid>%';
```

Comment: that was actually my solution. was so weird to check back and see someone had suggested that. it sped things up by 400%, so this is an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how much you need to query this data, storing it as XML might not be the best approach; assuming that you've already decided that it is, many databases support some form of XPath queries which can be used to extract data out of XML fields.  [MySQL provides some support](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/xml-functions.html) in the form of the ExtractValue function, which can be used to extract the criteria that you need in a more reliable way than simply using LIKE (e.g. in deefactorial's answer; what if there was more than one itemid in your XML?).

An example can be seen here on SO, in [How to use XPATH in MySQL select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349459/how-to-use-xpath-in-mysql-select).