# Storing misc data in a database

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

This is a general 'database' question that's been on my mind for the past couple of days.

I have a `User` table, which houses all the user details. But, i need to save misc data. How best is it to do this? I notice WordPress has a `wp_options` table which stores misc data (this question isn't related to WordPress).

Is this a sensible way to hold that kind of data?

**EDIT: additional info**

- the "misc" data should be searchable
- the misc data are mix of numeric, alphanumeric, "special" (e.g.: geo-coordinates)
- the user can invent new "types"? Like tags for example?
- Most users will have additional misc data, but I can't imagine having more than 200 users. Each with about 10 misc pieces of data (that doesn't fit into the users table)

Comment: Question is a bit vague. Do you intend to make the "misc" data searchable, for a start? Are they all of the same type (strings) or can these be a mix of numeric, alphanumeric, "special" (e.g.: geo-coordinates)? Can the user invent new "types"? Like tags for example?

Comment: Yeah, an other question, that pops into my mind: How many percentage of the User records will have any piece of this misc kind of data?

Comment: Sorry, yeah to most of them. They'll be various datatypes (int, varchar, longtext), and I'll want to add more as I go on.

Comment: Most users will have additional data, but I can't imagine having more than 200 users. Each with about 10 misc pieces of data (that doesn't fit into the users table).

Comment: So you want a meta table for structures that you cannot plan as of now?

Comment: What about transactional consistency? Because what you are describing seems to be better served by one of those newfangled NOSQL products... and 200 users is small potatoes, so maybe you should look into those anyway?

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of common solutions to this within relational databases.

The options that work within a database environment are the use of an "entity-attribute-value" or [EAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) schema. This makes it easy to store and retrieve data, but hard to validate it (e.g. "age must be between 0 and 100"), or run complex queries (e.g. "find users within 20 miles of geocode x whose address begins with "Laystall Steet" and whose age is greater than 22").

The second option is to use XML to store the non-relational data in your MySQL table, and use the [XPath support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349459/how-to-use-xpath-in-mysql-select) to query it.

Answer (score 0):

The relational model does not "shine" in dealing with tag-like structures. Especially user-extendable ones.

Considering the small size of your DB, I suggest you to either switch to a [NOSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) solution or to go for something like Json fields in Postgres, so you can mix proper relational with your extendable tag-like system. Support for searches is in beta, I understand, but you can get [an idea of how it works here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10560394/how-do-i-query-using-fields-inside-the-new-postgresql-json-datatype).