# How do I use regex to search records in sql that contain # tag, but ignore #FFFFFF or any other colors inside html tags

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter, mysqli

I'm using codeigniter as the framework. I am setting up a filter option to display items from an SQL database that contain hash tags, it's working great, however it's also returning records that include html tags, for example

```
 style="color:#f00; color:#ff0000;  ETC
```

It's only # tags inside

I've done a bit of research and having limited knowledge with regex (it's like a foreign language to me!).

This works fine.

```
$hashtag = "#" . $hashtag;
$this->db->like("feed_item.content", $hashtag);
```

I think I need something like this (struggling with it).

```
$sq = "/^(?![\"\'].*#.*[\"\']).*$/m";
$this->db->where('LOWER(otherColumn) REGEXP', $sq);
```

I copied the code above, and tried modifying it, just does nothing.

I'm not getting any errors, but that's typical with PHP :( 
It's not returning any output when I do this:

```
public function get_hashtag_feed($hashtag, $userid, $page) 
   {
    $hashtag = "#" . $hashtag;
    $sq = $re = '/^(?!["\'].*#.*["\']).*$/m/g';
    //$this->db->like("feed_item.content", $hashtag);


    return $this->db
        ->select("feed_item.ID, feed_item.content, feed_item.post_as,
            feed_item.timestamp, feed_item.userid, feed_item.likes,

feed_item_polls.question as poll_question, feed_item_polls.type as poll_type,

feed_item_polls.votes as poll_votes,
            user_blog_posts.Id as blog_postid, user_blog_posts.title as blog_post_title,
            user_blog_posts.image as blog_post_image")
        ->join("users", "users.ID = feed_item.userid")
        ->join("user_images", "user_images.ID = feed_item.imageid", "left outer")
        ->join("user_albums", "user_albums.ID = user_images.albumid", "left outer")
        ->join("user_videos", "user_videos.ID = feed_item.videoid", "left outer")
        ->join("users as profile", "profile.ID = feed_item.profile_userid", "left outer")
        ->join("feed_item_polls", "feed_item_polls.ID = feed_item.pollid", "left outer")
        ->join("user_blog_posts", "user_blog_posts.ID = feed_item.blog_postid", "left outer")
        ->join("pages", "pages.ID = feed_item.pageid", "left outer")
        ->join("page_users", "page_users.pageid = feed_item.pageid AND page_users.userid = " . $userid, "LEFT OUTER")
        ->join("calendar_events", "calendar_events.ID = feed_item.eventid", "left outer")
        ->join("feed_likes", "feed_likes.postid = feed_item.ID AND feed_likes.userid = " . $userid, "LEFT OUTER")
        ->join("user_saved_posts", "user_saved_posts.postid = feed_item.ID AND user_saved_posts.userid = " . $userid, "left outer")
        ->join("feed_item_subscribers", "feed_item_subscribers.postid = feed_item.ID and feed_item_subscribers.userid = " . $userid, "LEFT OUTER")
        ->where("LOWER(otherColumn) REGEXP", $sq)
        ->order_by("feed_item.ID", "DESC")
        ->limit(10,$page)
        ->get("feed_item");
```

Comment: I'm assigning $sq as a variable that holds the regex epression.  I'm using codeigniter framework, modifying existing code.  I've tried looking in documentation but not making sense with relation to regex.  https://www.mohdish.com/user_guide/#database-reference

Comment: I'm confused as to why you're not using the version that you say is working

Comment: Because the version that works, returns all records that contain a # tag, including records like this <p style="text-align: center;"><font size="6" color="#ff4136">Just a friend Alison from years ago!</font></p>  The # tag is embedded as color which I want to exclude.

Comment: But that result would only be returned if someone _searched_ for "ff4136", wouldn't it?  I'd say that's probably unlikely.  That said, it sounds like your db design could probably use some optimization.  That's outside the scope of this specific question though.

Comment: I've updated the question to include a larger segment of the code.

Comment: No, the query is to select all from table row $content WHERE like %#% excluding all colors, that's what I am trying to do

Comment: According to the function definition, you are searching for a specific term that you happen to be deciding must be preceded by a "#".  `public function get_hashtag_feed($hashtag, $userid, $page) `  That `$hashtag` value is the search term.  If the value of `$hashtag` is "myterm", then only records that contain "#myterm" should be returned.

Comment: If your data contains well-formed XML then most modern RDBMSs should be able to make use of xPath to perform your query.

Comment: As I said initially, part of it is the original code, I want it to be something like, select from table name where like %#% AND not equal to some expression that is a regex that does not include records that are a color.

Comment: I am the RDBM!  Can you elaborate on this please @MonkeyZeus?  As stated initially new to regex, so if there is an alternative?

Comment: What if the content contains a link with a fragment delimited by a "#"?  What if the content contains a list where I'm saying "#1 Bob Smith, #2 Sarah Jay, #3 Alfred Hitchcock"?

Comment: @StephenArmstrong-Smith Well first you need to learn xPath but your requirement is very easy so you simply need `//*[contains(text(), "#hashtag")]`. Now check out https://stackoverflow.com/q/349459/2191572 and you should have a working solution.

Comment: If you need to practice xPath then use Chrome, press F12, go to the console tab, and try out `$x('//*[contains(text(), "#hashtag")]')` against various pages.

Comment: I just want to exclude #colors anything else is outside the scope of my question.

Comment: LOL, that's a sure-fire attitude to cause yourself issues for years to come. Best of luck to you

Comment: I don't know what you mean?  I just asked a difficult question, I don't care about anything else as links are parsed before entering my dataset, as such they are not relevant.  html tags for styling are permitted though.

Comment: @PatrickQ, if it contains a list with numbers as you mentioned above, that's fine as it's inside the displayed text.  As such when the results are shown, it shows # 1, #2 etc.  It's confusing for users when they see records but no # tag

Comment: @StephenArmstrong-Smith The simple answer is that regex is not the proper tool for this.  It is not intended for parsing HTML, and rarely does a good job at it.  As MZ indicated, you should try xPath.  If you combine the example above with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/350180), you should at the least be able to come up with the basis for an xPath-focused question, if not your actual desired result.

Comment: I'm trying to filter records though, not parse them.  The records are text users enter, so will not be in an XML format.

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out just now, quite straightforwards when you have the answer.

This is the code that I'm using, it needs a tiny bit of refining but it's working perfectly using REGEXP.

```
$this->db->where("!(feed_item.content REGEXP '#(([a-fA-F0-9]){3})') AND feed_item.content like '%#%'");
```

Comment: What if the content is "world's best #dad"?

Comment: What if the content is `I'm so #fab`? Or `Your idea is #bad`?